# JBoss ESB pipeline interceptor triggers multiple times

Tags: jboss, interceptor, jboss6.x, jboss-esb

I am working on a project that "sniffs" (intercepts) all messages that are being send through ESB.

I use JBoss AS 6 with ESB 4.11. I am sending both esb-aware and JMS messages and everything works, but it seems that my interceptor intercepts every message mulptiple times.

At the moment, the Interceptor class just prints the concent + some other stuff to console. When I send a message, it displays the sent message multiple times (3 times to be more specific).

So my question is: **Why?**. Is this normal behavior? I have no clue where the mistake could be. I think that is could be one of these two options:

1) I have some error in my sending class, but I dont think thats the issue, since I use simply one serviceInvoker and my code is very similar to sample quickstarts. Standard output from gateway listeners also indicate that message is sent only ones...
2) Pipeline Interceptor intercepts the message multiple times, every time at a different stage of the pipeline. But how to test if this is the issue?

My properties file section for interceptors looks like this:

```
<properties name="interceptors">
    <property name="org.jboss.soa.esb.pipeline.failure.interceptors" value="interceptor.Interceptor"/>
      <property name="org.jboss.soa.esb.pipeline.instantiate.interceptors" value="interceptor.Interceptor"/>
    <property name="org.jboss.soa.esb.pipeline.start.interceptors" value="interceptor.Interceptor"/>
    <property name="org.jboss.soa.esb.pipeline.end.interceptors" value="interceptor.Interceptor"/>
</properties>
```

I tried to delete some of the properties but then it either doesnt intercept anything at all or it triggers multiple times!

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBossESB is not a very popular topic here :D

Eventually, I figured it out (I got helped on Jboss community forum). The problem is apparently a bug which is fixed in the next version of ESB. I hope this answer helps someone eventually...

Here is the link to the bug:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBESB-3876?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel